# How can I simulate a NOR gate in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to simulate a [NOR gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOR_gate) in JavaScript?

From what I have seen so far, the language has only AND and OR.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, the easiest way is: `!(a || b)`

Comment: Indeed. :) Short & sweet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a reversed && like so:

```
var a = false;
var b = false;

if ( !a && !b ) {
    // some code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Always you could negate the logic or making something like this:

```
if(!(true || true))
```

This way, you are always going to obtain the *or* result negated, which really has a NOR gate behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the bitwise version:

```
~(a | b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more versatile approach:

```js
function nor(...args:boolean[]){
    return !args.some(arg => arg)
}
```

And if your inputs are in some other form:

```js
function nor(...args){
    return !args.some(arg => !!arg)
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This is a NOT-AND gate which is equal to an AND gate followed by a NOT gate.

```
if(!(a && b)) { // code }
```

Comment: a NAND gate and a NOR gate are completely different

Comment: Bro, these are completely different